# boolean is set to false by default when passed in SOAP request

Tags: java, soap, null, boolean

**Situation** : I am coding a web service in which soap client sends the request to web service which will update the database.

Suppose, there is a table project_team_members and service will be updating info of individual team member.
There is a column in table IS_TEAM_LEADER which can have '0' or '1' as value.

**Problem**: When updating TL info, if I am not sending IS_TL field from SOUP UI (A SOAP Client), it is automatically received as 'false' by default in java code.

How can i know if user is sending it or not, i mean i am not able to send null in case of boolean data-type from SOAP client

Comment: Including some of your code will help us answer your question.

Comment: If there is any field, e.g. `Foo`, there is often an associated `IsFooSpecified` property to determine if the value was set or not. If there an `IsIsTeamLeadSpecified` property you can access?

Comment: yes there is method ISISTeamLead and its returning false, even if client does not sends it. may be boolean is by default initiating to false value,.,.,how can i get rid of this ???

Comment: //below is example code

if((!IsTeamLead())&& (DBBean.IsTeamLead().equals("1")))
        {throw new somePredefinedException();
        }
 else
{ toBePersistBean.IsTeamLead(recievedBean.IsTeamLead() ? "1" : "0");
}

Answer (score 0):

Revisiting my own question after so many years.
Giving response to myself at 2012 :)

One option can be, to send whatever is there in the database as it is, back to the server. But for this prior read call is necessary.

Another option is given by Jesse's(comment under question) as an answer/solution

> If there is any field, e.g. Foo, there is often an associated
>   IsFooSpecified property to determine if the value was set or not. If
>   there an IsIsTeamLeadSpecified property you can access?

PS: There wasn't any field as suggested by Jesse but this can help someone else.